# Array printing on the page with while cuts off

Tags: php, arrays

I have this loop that goes through the array and prints it out. The problem is that lets say there are 8 elements in this array. If 5th array does not agree with this **$scheduleFirstLine[10][$sfl] == 1** the while cuts off. It does not continue for 6th 7th and 8th items. How do I fix that problem?

```
while ($scheduleFirstLine[10][$sfl] == 1)
        {
            echo '
            <tr>
                <td style="color:'.$scheduleFirstLine[8][$sfl].';background-color:'.$scheduleFirstLine[9][$sfl].';">
                    '.$scheduleFirstLine[1][$sfl].'<br />'.$scheduleSecondLine[1][$sfl].'</td>
                <td style="color:'.$scheduleFirstLine[8][$sfl].';background-color:'.$scheduleFirstLine[9][$sfl].';">
                    '.$scheduleFirstLine[2][$sfl].'<br />'.$scheduleSecondLine[2][$sfl].' </td>
                <td style="color:'.$scheduleFirstLine[8][$sfl].';background-color:'.$scheduleFirstLine[9][$sfl].';">
                    '.$scheduleFirstLine[3][$sfl].'<br />'.$scheduleSecondLine[3][$sfl].' </td>
                <td style="color:'.$scheduleFirstLine[8][$sfl].';background-color:'.$scheduleFirstLine[9][$sfl].';">
                    '.$scheduleFirstLine[4][$sfl].'<br />'.$scheduleSecondLine[4][$sfl].' </td>
                <td style="color:'.$scheduleFirstLine[8][$sfl].';background-color:'.$scheduleFirstLine[9][$sfl].';">
                    '.$scheduleFirstLine[5][$sfl].'<br />'.$scheduleSecondLine[5][$sfl].' </td>
                <td style="color:'.$scheduleFirstLine[8][$sfl].';background-color:'.$scheduleFirstLine[9][$sfl].';">
                    '.$scheduleFirstLine[6][$sfl].'<br />'.$scheduleSecondLine[6][$sfl].' </td>
                <td style="color:'.$scheduleFirstLine[8][$sfl].';background-color:'.$scheduleFirstLine[9][$sfl].';">
                    '.$scheduleFirstLine[7][$sfl].'<br />'.$scheduleSecondLine[7][$sfl].' </td>            
            </tr>
            ';
            $sfl++;
        }
```

Comment: You should use a for loop and do an if else statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your while condition and use an if inside the loop.

```
$max = count($scheduleFirstLine[10]);
$sfl = 0;
while ($sfl < $max) {
    if ($scheduleFirstLine[10][$sfl] != 1)
        continue; // ignore these values
    // rest of the code
}
```

---

I would also suggest changing the structure of your array. Yours looks like this:

```
Array(
    Array( // attribute 1
        attribute 1 of 1st element,
        attribute 1 of 2nd element,
    )
    Array( // attribute 2
        attribute 2 of 1st element,
        attribute 2 of 2nd element,
    )
    ...
)
```

Instead of spreading the elements across all values, store all attributes that belong to one element together like this:

```
Array(
    Array( // 1st element
        attribute 1,
        attribute 2,
    )
    Array( // 2nd element
        attribute 1,
        attribute 2,
    )
    ...
)
```

You could then use the following code:

```
foreach ($array as $element) {
    if ($element[10] != 1)
        continue;

    echo '...'.$element[8].'...'.$element[1].'..';//etc.
}
```

Which is better to understand and modify in the future, because as I said, the attributes now belong to an element (and are stored all together!)

Comment: Thank you very much, because I have three different arrays and seems very complicated for me to figure this out I'll go with fixing what I have now, thank you!

Comment: three arrays: $scheduleFirstLine = simple_fields_get_post_group_values(get_the_id(), "Schedule First Line", false, 1);
  $scheduleSecondLine = simple_fields_get_post_group_values(get_the_id(), "Schedule Second Line", false, 1);
  $schedulePriceCodes = simple_fields_get_post_group_values(get_the_id(), "Schedule Price Codes", false, 1);